# How to change the color of font everytime the value change?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I just want to ask if is it possible to change the color of the font when the value changes ? just like how trading platform works it will ticks the font . It changes the color from white to green ( when the value goes up and )
so I want to [change the color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZGk4.png) of failed to red for 1 second when the value goes up and I want to change the color of sent to green for 1 second when the value goes up . is it possible to add the code inside the table cell ? thank you

here's the code of the table Cell

```
<TableCell sx={{ border:0.1,fontSize: 11.5, fontWeight: 200 }} align="center" style={{ paddingTop: 0,paddingBottom: 0,paddingLeft: 0,paddingRight:0, }}>{port.chargeCnt}</TableCell>
```

Comment: [React State](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html)

Comment: Other than Javascript, what technology are you using? `<TableCell sx={{...` ?

Comment: Im using react app @bloodyKnuckles

Comment: No where in the question is it mentioned that you are using React. Please edit your question to include this crucial detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to:

- Track the previous value (use the `usePrevious` hook)
- Compare it to the current value whenever the current value changes and use that to determine what colour to set it to
- Add a `setTimeout` function to reset the colour to the default after a second
- Handle the case where the value changes again before the reset has happened (by cancelling the timeout waiting to reset it).
- Cancel that timeout when the component unmounts (so you don't try to set a state that no longer exists).

Such:

```
import { usePrevious } from 'react-use';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const ChangingValue = ({ value }) => {
    const previous = usePrevious(value);
    const [color, setColour] = useState('black');
    const [timeoutId, setTimeoutId] = useState(0);
    useEffect(() => {
        clearTimeout(timeoutId);
        if (value > previous) {
            setColour('green');
        } else if (value < previous) {
            setColour('red');
        } else {
            setColour('black');
        }
        const newTimeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
            setColour('black');
        }, 1000);
        setTimeoutId('newTimeoutId');
        return () => clearTimeout(newTimeoutId);
    }, [value]);
    return <div style={{ color }}>{value}</div>;
};
```